# Is my SCSI controller faulty?

Tags: hardware, scsi

I have connected an old pci buslogic SCSI (i need for retrocomputing experiment)

`lspci` said

```
06:06.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: BusLogic Device [104b:0150]
```

No driver loaded, no disk recognized. Is it faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PCI device id doesn’t match any BusLogic controller supported by the kernel. On top of that, SCSI PCI cards have their own category, “SCSI storage controller”. This suggests that your card is faulty.

You could try modifying the `buslogic` driver to recognise your card, but it’s probably not worth it compared to the cost of a second-hand PCI SCSI controller.

Comment: The controller works now, very strange, if I attach to an adaptor for 80pin sca disk, works bad, if attacched to a classic scsi disk..works.

Comment: Wow that is strange!